# Where to include PHP exception in the class?

Tags: php, class, exception, methods

I'm new to OO PHP...I'm trying to create a PHP class called `MyClass` and some methods that should:

1. validate that parameters are numeric
2. validate that parameters are defined
3. if any of the above fail I need to send an exception with explanation

I've done 1. and 2. but don't know how to deal with exceptions, where you need to include them? Inside `MyFunction` method of inside `isNumeric/isDefined` methods. Could you please help to sort this issue.

My script:

```
<?php

namespace Quotations;

class MyClass {

var $is_number;
var $is_defined;
private $number;
private $defined;

private function isNumeric($w, $c){
    if(is_numeric($w) && is_numeric($c)){
        $number = true;
    }
    else{
        $number = false;
    }

    return $number;
}

private function isDefined($t, $f, $w, $c){
    if(isset($t, $f, $w, $c)){
        $defined = true;
    }
    else{
        $defined = false;
    }

    return $defined;
}

function MyFunction($to, $from, $weight, $cube) {
    try{
        if(!$this -> isNumeric($weight, $cube)){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Arguments are not numeric');
        }

        if(!$this -> isDefined($to, $from, $weight, $cube)){
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Arguments are missing');
        }
    }catch(InvalidArgumentException $e){
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }catch(BadMethodCallException $e){
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: `if (!is_numeric($w)) throw new Exception("$w is not numeric");`

Comment: note that with exceptions, if the parent/caller doesn't `catch` that exception at some point in the call stack, the exception can/will bubble all the way up to the top of the stack and kill the entire script with an "unhandled exception error".

Comment: `var` is PHP4. Use [`private`, `protected` or `public`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Similar for `function MyFunction(...)`. Without a visibility specifier it defaults to `public` but it is recommended to specify the method visibility than to rely on the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
function MyFunction($to, $from, $weight, $cube) {
    if(!$this -> isDefined($to, $from, $weight, $cube)){
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Arguments are missing');
    }
    if(!$this -> isNumeric($weight, $cube)){
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Arguments are not numeric');
    }
    //do stuff
}
```

And thats how you can handle it:

```
try{
    $MyClassObject->MyFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4);
}catch(BadMethodCallException $e){
    //handle missing arguments ...
}catch(InvalidArgumentException $e){
    //handle invalid argumets ...
}
```

So, thats just an example of basic usage. Feel free to adjust it however you want.

Note, if you have missing non-optional arguments in function, PHP will produce E_WARNING

Comment: I've added your code into my script but I can't load it in the browser (localhost is currently unable to handle this request.). I've By the way this is how I call my method: 

quotation = new Quotations\MyClass();
echo $quotationResult = $quotation -> MyFunction('A', 'B', 2, 3).' How would you show that error in a browser?

Comment: The reason I could not load the script was because you forgot ; inside second if statement

Comment: I'm assuming that you handle exception outside of class, right? Would it be possible to create an exception and handle it inside same class? Sorry for these questions, I'm just new to OO PHP...

Comment: Off course, you can cacth it whenever you want, even right after it was throwed. Exceptions are bubble up.http://php.net/manual/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Thanks for you help! Last question - How do you display (return) this exception message in your browser? I know how to return number, string, etc but not sure how to do it with exceptions?

Comment: If you mean, if it was catched - `echo $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really nice explained! Well done!

Comment: Have a look at my updated script above at the `MyFunction` method. I think it's right now. But when I'm calling this method like this:  `$quotation = new Quotations\MyClass(); echo $quotationResult = $quotation -> MyFunction('A', 'B', 2, 'a');` to test if it will throw an exception. But it doesn't load my script saying - "localhost is currently unable to handle this request". But when I call it like this:  `$quotation = new Quotations\MyClass(); echo $quotationResult = $quotation -> MyFunction('A', 'B', 2, 3);`  it work fine (i can see blank page).

Comment: First, you have missed closing bracket of `MyClass` which is parse error. Second, you have to qualify namespaces properly, since class is not in global namespace `\InvalidArgumentException` (which is my fault actually, edited the answer). And i see you have no separate logic to handle missing parameters and wrong parameters, so to avoid code duplication it is better to throw single class of exception in both cases (with different messages), so you will have only one catch block for it. Thats why this question is a bit too general, it is a simple model, but it really depends on what you want.